# Selecting a deeply nested link using xpath query

Tags: php, xpath, href

```
<body class="en-us">   <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="content-top">
        <div class="content-bot">
          <div id="profile-wrapper" class=
          "profile-wrapper profile-wrapper-horde">
            <div class="profile-sidebar-anchor">
              <div class="profile-sidebar-outer">
                <div class="profile-sidebar-inner">
                  <div class="profile-sidebar-contents">
                    <div class="profile-sidebar-crest">
                      <a href="/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/" rel="np" class="profile-sidebar-character-model" style="">
                      </a>

                      <div class="profile-sidebar-info">
                        <div class="name">
                          <a href="/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/"
                          rel="np">Glitchshot</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="under-name color-c8">
                          <span class="level"><strong>85</strong></span>
                          <a href="/wow/en/game/race/somerace" class="race">somerace</a> 
                          <a href="/wow/en/game/class/someclass" class="class">someclass</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="guild">
                          <a href="/wow/en/guild/some-server/someguild/?character=sometoon">
                          Some Guild</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="realm">
                          <span id="profile-info-realm" class="tip"
                          data-battlegroup="Stormstrike">Black
                          Dragonflight</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="profile-sidebar-menu" id="profile-sidebar-menu">
                      <li><a href=
                      "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/" class=
                      "back-to" rel="np"><span class="arrow"><span class=
                      "icon">Character Summary</span></span></a></li>

                      <li class="root-menu"><a href=
                      "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement"
                         class="back-to" rel="np"><span class=
                         "arrow"><span class=
                         "icon">Achievements</span></span></a></li>

                      <li class=" active"><a href=
                      "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#summary"
                         class="" rel="np"><span class="arrow"><span class=
                         "icon">Achievements</span></span></a></li>

                      <li class=""><a href=
                      "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#92"
                         class="" rel="np"><span class="arrow"><span class=
                         "icon">General</span></span></a></li>
```

I know that I have posted a lot of useless code here but wanted you guys to have an idea of wwhat the DOM would look like.

From this:

```
<a href="/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#92" class="" rel="np"><span class="arrow"><span class="icon">General</span></span></a>
```

I would like to extract this:

```
/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#92
```

which comes from the last anchor in the posted markup.

I have read as much as I can find on how to use xpath query to extract the needed information but I am clearly missing something.  Below is the query that I thought should work but does not.

```
<?php
    $query = '*/ul[@class=profile-sidebar-menu]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a/@href';
    echo $query . "<br>";
    $achievementSubCategory = $xpath->query($query);

    $achiSubArray = array("URL" => $achievementSubCategory->item(0)->nodeValue);
    var_dump($achiSubArray);
    // Produces array(1) { ["URL"]=> NULL } which should look something more like:
    // array(1) { ["URL"]=> /wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#92 }
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance and advice

Comment: Why do you need to extract that exact link, if you know the format of it? Why not generate it on your own?

Comment: I'm with @Dalton Conley.  You can easily extract links with javascript from the DOM.

Comment: I am trying to pull data from the wow armory, the links to the data that I need to pull is located in a static position.  I understand that I can pull this using javascript but am trying to do it server-side to eliminate the need for javascript for essential functionality

Comment: Additionally, I don't need just that link, but if i can pull that one, then i can loop through the rest of the links that follow.  Basically there are several categories that are statically located. I put these categories in an array then loop through the categories pulling the sub categories.

Comment: Please show all the html you are working on.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for discussion of the issues in your XPath expression and a complete and easy solution.

Comment: I apologize to all for having incomplete html.  I was under the assumption that I could get an answer close enough to what I needed with out filling the page up with the entire HTML.  As it turns out, the data sits in the DOM a little differently than how I thought it did.  I do not yet have it working yet, but I will be able to once i sift through the DOM a little better.  If you are curious, I posted a link to the wow armory page that I am referring to in one of my previous comments.  As it sits rite now, everybody has put out great information and good tools.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> */ul[@class=profile-sidebar-menu]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a/@href
> ```

**There are a few problems with this XPath expression**:

1. It is looking for a `ul` element that is a crandchild of the current node, and that has an attribute named `class` whose string value is equal to the string value of one of the children-elements of `ul`, named `profile-sidebar-menu`. However, the `ul` has no children named `profile-sidebar-menu` and the whole expression doesn't select any node.
2. Another problem is the indexing. `li[3]` selects the third `li` element - child of the context node. However the wanted `a` element is a child of the *fourth* `li` child of the context node. This must be expressed as: `li[4]`. XPath positions are 1-based, not 0-based.

**If these two problems are corrected, I believe that the corrected expression should look like the following**:

```
*/ul[@class="profile-sidebar-menu"]/ul/li[4]/a/@href
```

The absolute XPath expression that selects the wanted `href` attribute starting from the top element `body` of the provided XML document, is:

```
/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/ul/li[4]/a/@href
```

Below is the XML document (the provided one, made well-formed by appending a number of missing end tags:

```
<body class="en-us">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-top">
                <div class="content-bot">
                    <div id="profile-wrapper" class=
              "profile-wrapper profile-wrapper-horde">
                        <div class="profile-sidebar-anchor">
                            <div class="profile-sidebar-outer">
                                <div class="profile-sidebar-inner">
                                    <div class="profile-sidebar-contents">
                                        <div class="profile-sidebar-crest">
                                            <a href="/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/" rel="np" class="profile-sidebar-character-model" style=""></a>
                                            <div class="profile-sidebar-info">
                                                <div class="name">
                                                    <a href="/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/"
                              rel="np">Glitchshot</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="under-name color-c8">
                                                    <span class="level">
                                                        <strong>85</strong>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <a href="/wow/en/game/race/somerace" class="race">somerace</a>
                                                    <a href="/wow/en/game/class/someclass" class="class">someclass</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="guild">
                                                    <a href="/wow/en/guild/some-server/someguild/?character=sometoon">
                              Some Guild</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="realm">
                                                    <span id="profile-info-realm" class="tip"
                              data-battlegroup="Stormstrike">Black
                              Dragonflight</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <ul class="profile-sidebar-menu" id="profile-sidebar-menu">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href=
                          "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/" class=
                          "back-to" rel="np">
                                                    <span class="arrow">
                                                        <span class=
                          "icon">Character Summary</span></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="root-menu">
                                                <a href=
                          "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement"
                             class="back-to" rel="np">
                                                    <span class=
                             "arrow">
                                                        <span class=
                             "icon">Achievements</span></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class=" active">
                                                <a href=
                          "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#summary"
                             class="" rel="np">
                                                    <span class="arrow">
                                                        <span class=
                             "icon">Achievements</span></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="">
                                                <a href=
                          "/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#92"
                             class="" rel="np">
                                                    <span class="arrow">
                                                        <span class=
                             "icon">General</span></span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

One can check that the above absolute XPath expression selects exactly the wanted `href` attribute, by evaluating it with a tool like [**the Xpath Visualizer**](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html).

Here is a snapshot of the selection, performed with the XPath Visualizer:

[image]

Comment: How did you get this webapp to display the document like this?

Comment: @Wes: Did you read the answer? There is a link: "One can check that the above absolute XPath expression selects exactly the wanted href attribute, by evaluating it with a tool like the Xpath Visualizer". Just click on the link and then click on one of the two "download" icons.

Comment: @Wes: Here, at SO one is expected to accept the best of the answers. To accept an answer, simply click on the green check-mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks bro, I did read, and I would like to vote for your answer because it is a good answer but it did not work for me because I am not able to load my document into the webapp.  Was there anything that you had to do to get it to read your input properly?

Comment: @Wes: Of course, bro, There were a lot of ending tags missing and I added them myself (this is mentioned in my answer). You can just copy and paste the already corrected XML from my answer.

Comment: Or, if you are still unable to construct the well-formed XML document, just provide an email address and I will send it to that email address.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev  Thank you,  I know there were many tags left out.  I did this because I was trying to avoid posting too much code.  I pasted loaded the entire actual document that I would be working with. Here is a link to an example of one of the pages that I will be performing such searches on [http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/rustrazor/achievement#96]  My 3m@il is wes SPAMDOTSPAM erdman at SPAMgmailSPAM

Comment: @Wes: I sent you the XML -- do have a look at your mail.

Answer (score 0):

If your DOM structure is consistent, then something like the following should work:

```
//ul[@class='profile-sidebar-menu']/li[last()]/a/@href
```

Your xpath statement makes no sense.  You have multiple ul's in the path but the sample is not structured that way.  Also, indexing in xpath starts at 1, not 0.

Comment: I was afraid that not posting all of the html would lead to this.  There is an unknown number of links that will show up in the same way that the last link that I posted showed up as.  Thank you for your suggestion though.  Using a loop increment the number of <li> elements to get the next link until there are no more.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood how the query opperates. I think that $query = '*/ul[@class=profile-sidebar-menu]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/a/@href'; is = to $query = '*/ul[@class=profile-sidebar-menu]/ul/li/li/li/ul/li/li/a/@href';

Comment: I have made a mistake in my question by not posting enough HTML. There is another <ul> and some <li> that follow to the actual link that I need.  [link]http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/black-dragonflight/rustrazor/achievement#96 will take you to the page that I am looking at.  I need to be able to get the links that go to "Easter Kingdoms", "Kalimdor" etc etc.

Comment: The li[3] notation says to get 3rd li at the given level.  It is not a shorthand to specify depth.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.  I have tried replacing the li[3] with an actual representation of the proper depth such as /li/li/li etc but I still end up with an empty array.  Im at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure your xpath should start with "*/ul" instead of "//ul"?  I'm not a PHP programmer, so I'm not sure what the context is that your xpath expression is evaluated under.  The "*/ul" says to match all UL nodes that are grandchildren of the current context node.  I think the use of "*/ul" may be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the base of the html you show above (and assuming that final tags are correctly closed) the ewh'expression should work fine.

May be you omitted some important part of the document there. Try being more specific:

`//ul[@class='profile-sidebar-menu' and @id='profile-sidebar-menu']/li/a[@href='/wow/en/character/some-server/sometoon/achievement#92']/@href`

I'm pretty sure it works, tested online via [XPath Query Expression Tool](http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx).

If you still do not get results, try to show all the html you are working on.

Comment: This put me on the rite track.  I was not being spacific enough and was leaving out the id=.  I did not think it was required to have both of them.

Comment: Fine! Please mark this as the answer so that the thread can be closed.

Comment: I would except this requires that i know what the href value is in order to get the href value.  I need to get the href value of an anchor so that implies that I do not know the href value.